# How can I parameterize this base class variable?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a base class `Parent` that stores data for a test suite. All of its code is the same for different `TestCase`s, except for one variable, `raw_data_path`. I want to parameterize this variable, but I don't know how to.

```
class Parent():
    mapping_field_names = [
        'motion_rv', 'motion_lv', 'wall_motion_other'
    ]
    raw_data_path = make_path('input', 'raw_data.csv') # parameterize this variable
    transform = Transform(df=load(raw_data_path))
    transform.transform_df()

class TestMappings(unittest.TestCase, Parent):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.df = self.transform.df_mappings # uses `make_path('input', 'raw_data.csv')`
        return super().setUp()

class TestTransformData(unittest.TestCase, Parent):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.df = self.transform.df # uses `make_path('input', 'raw_data.csv')`
        return super().setUp()

class TestRawData(unittest.TestCase, Parent):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.df = self.transform.df # except I want this with `make_path('test', 'raw_data.csv')`
        return super().setUp()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining the Parent class like this.

```
class Parent():
       def __init__(self, raw_data_path):
              self.raw_data_path = raw_data_path
              self.transform = Transform(df=load(raw_data_path))
              self.transform.transform_df()
              self.mapping_field_names = [
                     'motion_rv', 'motion_lv', 'wall_motion_other'
              ]
```